# why grid lines + scale doesn't update, when controlled via python console?

Tags: python, scripting

I can successfully controll the grid_scale & grid_lines in bpy.types.SpaceView3D.

I know this, because the console tells me that my input has been recieved, for example, when I write: bpy.types.SpaceView3D.grid_lines
the console prints my new value.

**But here's my question: Why doesn't the values update in the Blender Properties panel**, I mean visually in my current scene? (check my print screen you can see the values haven't changed. - that's the problem.)

I'm new to scripting so a simplified answer would be brilliant.
Thanks / Dan[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Difference between a class and an instance.**

`bpy.types.SpaceView3D` is a class, it has a `grid_lines` property. The blender UI has a window, made up of screens, made up of areas, within each area an active space (what you see in that area). The active space in a view 3d area is an instance of the `bpy.types.SpaceView3D` class.

Running this code in the text editor will change all 3d view spaces grid lines to 10 and scale to 2

```
import bpy

for screen in bpy.data.screens:
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            area.spaces.active.overlay.grid_lines = 10
            area.spaces.active.overlay.grid_scale = 2
```

in the python console the active space is not a 3d view area, rather a python console.  Similar to above but in console

```
>>> type(C.space_data)
<class 'bpy.types.SpaceConsole'>

>>> for i, a in enumerate(C.screen.areas):
...     i, a.type
...     
(0, 'INFO')
(1, 'PROPERTIES')
(2, 'CONSOLE')
(3, 'VIEW_3D')
(4, 'TEXT_EDITOR')

>>> space3d = C.screen.areas[3].spaces.active
>>> type(space3d)
<class 'bpy.types.SpaceView3D'>

>>> space3d.overlay.grid_lines = 10
```

If the code is invoked, via a button or menu (for example),  in the context of the 3d view, then the 3D VIEW space would also be `context.space_data`

Comment: Brilliant answer! You made me understand what's going on, and thanks for your help, & for the perfect clarity!